# How can I search multiple things with one search string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I have a search bar on my app and if I type something in, the system looks it up (but only for one specific attribut).
Ex. "Hammer" only looks in Tool names.

But now I need to put in different kind of strings.
Like "Hammer" or the Barcode. So if I type in Hammer I want to see all tools where Hammer is in the name and if I type in the same field a barcode I want the results for the barcode.

Hope that does not sound confusing.

Until now I have the following:

```
paginatedData(){
    const start = this.pageNumber * this.size,
    end = start + this.size;
    this.totalNumber = Math.ceil(this.history_entries.length / this.size);
    console.log(this.totalNumber);
    this.search_result_counter = this.history_entries.filter(data => data.tool_name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())).slice(start, end).length;
    return this.history_entries.filter(data => data.tool_name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())).reverse().slice(start, end);
  }
```

That works perfectly fine just for the first descriped case.
I thought I could solve my problem by doing that:

```
this.search_result_counter = this.history_entries.filter(data => data.tool_name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())) || data.barcode.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())).slice(start, end).length;
    return this.history_entries.filter(data => data.tool_name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())) || data.barcode.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())).reverse().slice(start, end);
```

But it seems like that is not the right way.
I guess I need to put || somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

you have too many `)`s before your `||`s
Check your parenthesis

Comment: Oh, I see. But I just did it quickly to demonstrate what I already tried. Even when its correct - does not work. Makes the search bar just buggy.

Comment: after fixing the `)`s the code *looks* ok, do you have a simple example where it misbehaves? Be aware that start/end might give you out of range values after you filter your array (depending on your pagenumber when you change your search values)

Comment: you probably need to sanitize your pagination parameters (pagenumber, start, end) after you filter your array (and before splicing it).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest splitting the search string into an array, then forEach term call a function that searches one thing at a time, adding the results to an accumulating results list.
This way you can add as many search types as you like.  Adding new items will be a simple matter of adding it's identifier to an if else or switch case.